Disconnect from BT Device on Terminating App
So i'm trying to disconnect from a Bluetooth device upon terminating the app. I have tried using the AppDelegate functions and even subscribing to the NotificiationCeneter with an onReceive method for the willTerminate message, in both instances they fire off and I can see that they're at the very least being called which is where I have my device.cancelPeripheral... function and whatever is in the functions are attempting to fire. When i go to my Settings, however, I see that my device is still connected.
MyView()
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willTerminateNotification), perform: { output in
            print("TERMINATING FROM ONRECEIVE")
            guard let device = BTManager.connectedDevice else { return }
            BTManager.manager.cancelPeripheralConnection(device.peripheral)
        })

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        log("application will terminate")
        guard let device = BTManager.connectedDevice else { return }
            BTManager.manager.cancelPeripheralConnection(device.peripheral)
    }

Does the OS or phone cancel pending functions? I'm curious to find out why this is occurring

try applicationWillResignActive instead

I tried following this, but i can't even get the  willResignActive function to fire off so I don't think what i'm doing will even trigger it. but the idea to try it is much appreciated
